# Can't add my UI images to pyinstaller build (with .spec file)

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller, specifications

I've struggled getting my functioning app to include the images in it - thus far I've just included in the 'dist' folder manually and it works fine. But as I'm using --onefile, I want the images to be included in the standalone app.

There are a few similar answers on StackOverflow but none seem to work, especially as it seems to change periodically.

Below is all the latest of my attempts - my terminal/commandline call, and the .spec file I made (from various tutorials). Note that I haven't added anything to the python script, and the icon does work perfectly so my file structure isn't faulty. Any help would be great!

Commandline:

```
pyinstaller  --onefile --windowed DragDrop_27.spec
```

Spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['DragDrop_27.py'],
             pathex=['/Users/orange/PycharmProjects/imageMerge_01'],
             binaries=[],
         datas=[('bgimage.png', '.'), ('bgimageover.png', '.'), ('bgimagehover.png', '.'), ('bgimageprogress.png', '.'), ('play_logo.png', '.'), ('play_logoover.png', '.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
a.datas += [('bgimage.png', '.','DATA'), ('bgimageover.png', '.','DATA'), ('bgimagehover.png', '.','DATA'), ('bgimageprogress.png', '.','DATA'), ('play_logo.png', '.','DATA'), ('play_logoover.png', '.','DATA')]
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='DragDrop_27',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False )
app = BUNDLE(exe,
             name='DragDrop_27.app',
             icon='myicon.icns',
             bundle_identifier=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't think it is possible to have images in a stand-alone version unless it's strictly for personal use. I spent at least 4 hours attempting to fix this same issue but it didn't work. You can add an image with a .ico file and use it with --onefile but you won't be able to have others use it unless you give them the image file separately.

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon='Pig.ico' AnimalFacts.py
```

Comment: I've seen many people mentioning you *can* get it to work - its just that none if the solved questions work for me.